# Is it worth re-applying for a UK Visitor visa?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

Last year I applied for a UK visit visa to visit my husband's family, who are British citizens. At the time I applied from a country where I was a tourist in. The application was rejected due to not enough ties to my home country and personal financial circumstances. I did not provide any financial statements of my own and I didn't provide anything to show ties to my own country.

[image]

[image]

This time I am applying from my own country. I am currently unemployed, and I had previously been working abroad for a number of years so I don't have many ties in my home country. All I have is a bank account registered in my name but with basically no activity (with some savings), and I am registered as living in my mother's house (although we have different surnames). My father works abroad. These were not mentioned in the previous application.

As shown in the first bullet point above they acknowledged "documents relating to my husband's family" but they said my own personal and financial circumstances are important. But I am unemployed with no income except for some savings - financially, does that mean I can't apply unless I have my own income/substantial savings?

If it makes any difference I would be travelling with my husband who is a British citizen and our baby son. The reason is to visit my in-laws so they can meet their new grandson.

In summary, I can make the following changes to my application this time:

- Show a bank account in my name, with savings that would cover 90%-95% of my travel costs. However this is just a backup as I will be sponsored and is mainly to show I have at least something in my own country.
- Show that I am registered as living in an address in my home country.
- Show that my son was recently born and his grandparents would like to meet him. Technically he is a British citizen by descent (but doesn't yet have a British passport).

Comment: Did your husband sponsor your previous application and/or did you submit documents relating to *his* ties to your country of residence (I am presuming, possibly incorrectly, that you live together there)?

Comment: Yes he did. But no he didn't have any ties to my country so nothing was submitted for that.

Comment: Where does your British husband reside? If neither of you have ties to your country of residence but you *do have* ties to the UK IMHO you’re not likely to be given a visitor visa. In the eyes of the ECO, without a compelling reason to leave the UK the risk that you’d overstay would likely be considered high.

Comment: @dragosrsupercool Being married to a British citizen does *not* qualify the OP to apply for British citizenship. To do that, it is necessary to have lived in the UK for the last 3 years and to have either indefinite leave to remain (ILR) or settled status under the EU Settlement Scheme https://www.gov.uk/british-citizenship

Comment: @Traveller We have been travelling around for the last year and a half, not staying in one place for more than 5-6 months. But technically his residency is still the UK.

Comment: @dragosrsupercool Well I don't want to stay there but unfortunately that's not something I can show due to my circumstances (although my husband is here with me). The child is almost 3 months so he needs me, but also my husband and I don't want to be apart. Although I realise now that these probably won't convince the ECO.

Comment: Unfortunately, your reason seems more and more inclining being in UK. let's forget about financial and employment situation at home for a moment, what do you feel is major reason for you wanting to come back to your home country. "that reason" can only be the only thing that can convince ECO

Comment: @dragosrsupercool I want to come back because my mother and sisters are here, who I live with in the same house, as well as many other family members. But will the ECO accept this as a reason?

Comment: it could have been but then you also were not really with them in last few years, plus you're married with kid so you will be more inclined to be with your husbands family. 

if you can explain a strong bond between your mother and sisters and how it will be just impossible to say in different countries even when your husband and his parents lives in UK, then may be you have a chance

Comment: @dragosrsupercool OK I understand better now. Thank you for explaining.

Answer (score 3):

> But I am unemployed with no income except for some savings - financially, does that mean I can't apply unless I have my own income/substantial savings?

This is a criterion that they assess yes, having very little amount of money and especially not working would make them think you're abandoning everything to work illegally in the UK.

See [this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab) about why bank accounts are so important

> I did not provide any financial statements of my own and I didn't provide anything to show ties to my own country.

You should always provide the required documents. Being sponsored doesn't exclude them from reviewing your own situation (they aren't assessing the sponsor, they're assessing you).

---

> so I don't have many ties in my home country

This is bad. You need to have ties to your own country (work, property (home, car...) in your name, family...). You seem to have neither and way more ties to the UK, this *may* lead to swift refusal.

Either way, you need to show as much proof as possible of your ties in your country and no one can be sure of your fate unless you apply again